# Arquillian : Dependency Injection not working

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to use Arquillian to run tests on a remote Wildfly server. I am not sure why the Dependency Injection does not work. Here is the relevant section from POM:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.Alpha10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<profile>
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-remote -->
            <id>arq-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0.Alpha3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
```

My test class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.avm.service.ITestService;
import com.avm.service.TestService;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class OrderServiceTest {

        @Deployment
        public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
            return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "backend.war")
                    .addClass(ITestService.class)
                    .addClass(TestService.class)
                    //.addPackage(RepositoryManager.class.getPackage()).addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
                    .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        }

        @Inject
        @Named("testService")
        TestService testService;

        @Test
        public void testRegister() throws Exception {
            Assert.assertEquals("backend", testService.getAppName());
        }
    }
```

Service Interface:

```
public interface ITestService {
    String getAppName();
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
@Named("testService")
public class TestService implements ITestService{

    private String appName = "backend";
    private String version = "1.0.0";

    @Override
    public String getAppName() {
        return this.appName;
    }
}
```

Finally, my arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <!-- Force the use of the Servlet 3.0 protocol with all containers, as it is the most mature -->
    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

    <!-- Uncomment to have test archives exported to the file system for inspection -->
    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
    </engine>

    <!-- Example configuration for a managed WildFly / JBoss EAP instance -->
    <container qualifier="managed">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">/git/Servers/wildfly-26.1.1.Final</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

    <!-- Example configuration for a remote WildFly / JBoss EAP instance -->
    <container qualifier="remote">
        <!-- Arquillian will deploy to this WildFly server. -->
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
            <property name="managementPort">9990</property>

        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

After hunting down a solution for about two days now and having tried almost anything which I could, I feel I would really appreciate if a kind soul looked at this problem now.

Thanks for reading, appreciate your time.

Comment: Happy to add more details in case there is anything missing. Please let me know.

Comment: I do not really know, a few pointers in case they may help: (1) there is a version discrepancy between arquillian-junit-container & arquillian-protocol-servlet (2) can you try placing the empty beans.xml file in other relevant places, like root META-INF, WEB-INF/classes/META-NF? (3) can you try adding a scope annotation like @ApplicationScoped in TestService? Good luck anyway!

Comment: Thanks for being helpful. I did try putting the beans xml into other places and did infact try the ApplicationScoped annotation. Didn’t work for me. I keep getting a NPE.